# How to detect users Computer Specs and Hardware

Tags: html, hardware

I want to create a page which is able to automatically detect a users computer spec and hardware they are using. Is there some way i can find this out? Has someone perhaps already created something which does this i can use?

The information I am interested in displaying on a web page is:

- cpu
- ram
- mouse
- keyboard
- monitor

Comment: PHP is server side, not client side, so can never detect these stuff on the user's ccomputer

Comment: COuld i use javascript to achieve what i want?

Comment: As far as I know, that is impossible even with JS, as that would be security issue.

Comment: And what hardware specs you want to know? You can check `$_SERVER`.

Comment: Are you asking about the specs of the computer that the server is running, or the specs of the computer that accesses it?

Comment: Exactly which aspects of the hardware spec are you hoping to auto-detect?

Comment: I want to create a webpage, which can show the user on the browser there own computer spec, cpu/ram etc and there own hardware, mouse/keyboard/monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language. You are not able to detect computer specs. However, you can use  JavaScript to detect some basic screen related things like resolution, pixel depth, colors etc.

PHP is able to detect network information and some settings.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

In JS you can get some of this information:

Computer Memory (only supported in chrome):

`console.log('Memory', navigator.deviceMemory);`

Computer Cores:

`console.log('Cores', navigator.hardwareConcurrency);`

Connection Speed:

`console.log('Connection', navigator.connection);`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an exploit into users' privacy. There won't be any universal way to do that but there may be ways for certain combinations of operating systems, browsers and plugins. You could certainly use a browser extension users could install in their computers, or even a binary executable that would send out the results that could later be accessed on your website.

Comment: Obviously they would be visting the site page for the purpose of seeing this and would require permission. Much like how this website detects system requirements. http://www.systemrequirementslab.com

Comment: I'm not accusing you of bad intentions, just trying to explain why there's no standard way to do that.